# This [discount] has expired!

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discount) tag has nearly 400 questions and obviously judging by the name, it is **not** related to programming.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Sort of. This tag is very ambiguous and doesn't point to the same thing all the time.

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No! Most questions use it for shopping discounts. How is that related to programming?

3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. Most of the time questions ask about code that has something to do with discounts when shopping. Mention the code problem, not the discount!

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No but sometimes. It's mostly used for shopping discounts, but is also used for [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447322/using-contain-operator-in-shopify-ruby-for-cart-discount-code-not-working) sometimes which is on-topic.

Here's the thing, most questions actually ask simple questions like rounding errors, max-min, sorting etc., of which the discount tag isn't needed. Some questions **do** have to mention discount, e.g. for removing tax to get the actual price, which seems to be on-topic. Maybe the questions can be retagged instead of the tag being burninated if the community thinks otherwise?

Comment: Looking at that tag, it leads to a wealth of other off topic things, like [[tag:price]], [[tag:product]], [[tag:coupon]], [[tag:tax]]

Comment: Better burninate this tag before black Friday.

Comment: "Let's take 100% off of [discount]"

Comment: *"No [discount] for you, my friend!"*

Comment: I find questions about discount **calculation** to be perfectly **on-topic** on Stack Overflow. While some of such questions could be tagged with more generic tag (something like "percentage"), for commerce-oriented frameworks the notion of "discount" could be more native. "4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?" - Well, the meaning of "discount" is the **always the same**, even in off-topic questions. And the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447322/using-contain-operator-in-shopify-ruby-for-cart-discount-code-not-working) is about that meaning.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree, the problem with this kind of burnination request is that we don't have a subject matter expert explaining if "discount" is a functionality or feature of for example "woocomerce" or "shopify"... The tag might even be on-topic and a programming feature/functionality that's shared by a number of APIs, who knows?! Having participated in burninations I've had to retag a lot of stuff that I just couldn't evalute, and it's frequent for woocomerce questions that are seemingly off-topic to be actually meaningful for devs working with that technology.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: There really ought to be one tag then; something about bill calculation. But neither [total] nor [discount] really seem to do the job.

Comment: "This [discount] has expired"